# opendj 3.0 replication failed to start for about 2m entries

Tags: opendj

I'm testing opendj 3.0 replicatoin.

I have two opendj nodes which is a replica. The replication works nice.
But when I added about 2m entries, one opendj node failed to restart. I tried several times, but no luck. According to server.out, looks like some TimedOut, I'm not sure if it's related.

Any idea or workaround.  I followed https://forum.forgerock.com/topic/replication-server-timed-out-waiting-for-monitor-data/  , add changed the monitor data timeout from 5 seconds to 60 seconds, and still no luck.

[03/Aug/2017:04:44:20 -0400] category=PLUGGABLE severity=NOTICE msgID=org.opends.messages.backend.513 msg=The database backend userRoot containing 2075308 entries has started
[03/Aug/2017:04:44:21 -0400] category=EXTENSIONS severity=NOTICE msgID=org.opends.messages.extension.221 msg=DIGEST-MD5 SASL mechanism using a server fully qualified domain name of: stg2-n6.nscloud.local
[03/Aug/2017:04:44:22 -0400] category=SYNC severity=NOTICE msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.204 msg=Replication server RS(31748) started listening for new connections on address 0.0.0.0 port 8989
[03/Aug/2017:04:44:23 -0400] category=SYNC severity=NOTICE msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.62 msg=Directory server DS(27712) has connected to replication server RS(31748) for domain "cn=admin data" at stg2-n6.nscloud.local/192.168.30.46:8989 with generation ID 161237
[03/Aug/2017:04:45:23 -0400] category=SYNC severity=WARNING msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.106 msg=Timed out waiting for monitor data for the domain "cn=schema" from replication server RS(19987)
[03/Aug/2017:04:46:23 -0400] category=SYNC severity=WARNING msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.106 msg=Timed out waiting for monitor data for the domain "dc=example,dc=com" from replication server RS(19987)
[03/Aug/2017:04:46:23 -0400] category=SYNC severity=WARNING msgID=org.opends.messages.replication.106 msg=Timed out waiting for monitor data for the domain "cn=admin data" from replication server RS(19987)

Comment: The replication monitor data timeout thing is harmless. Just an indication that replication status may not be accurate due to slow responses.

Comment: You said the server fail to restart. What are the errors, what are the symptoms if there is no error ? Is the server running but not indicated it's ready ? Is the process killed or stopped ? We have customers with several tens of millions of users in their directory services, replicated across multiple geos... So I'm not sure how to help without further details.